# Second ul li elements (inside another ul) are displaying over first ul

Tags: css

I have two  items - one inside another.
The problem is that secon  items are displayed on top of the first ul li items.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item-101"><a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-102 current active deeper parent"><a href="/index.php/merchants-shops">Merchants / Shops</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="item-104"><a href="/index.php/merchants-shops/hottest-discounts">Hottest Discounts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item-105"><a href="/index.php/merchants-shops/training-and-advice">Training and advice</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item-106"><a href="/index.php/merchants-shops/call-our-manager">Call our manager</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-103"><a href="/index.php/contact-us">Contact us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}

#left #menu ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
}
#left #menu ul.menu li {
    background-image: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/menu_bulta.png), url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/menu_fons.png);
    background-position: 210px 7px, left 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 250px;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#left #menu ul.menu li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 15px 0 0 17px;
    color: #336699;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#left #menu ul.menu li.current {
    background-image:none;
    background-color: #1F5CA9;
}

#left #menu ul.menu li.current a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

#left #menu ul.menu li.current ul li {
    background-image:none;
    background-color: #1F5CA9;
}

#left #menu ul.menu li.current ul li a {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #c6e3ff;
}
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5he9Y/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `height: 44px` in your CSS, use `min-height: 44px`.

See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5he9Y/1/).

On a related note, giving height in px is not a recommended idea because it is not scalable when users increase the font size (or zoom) of the web browser.